# SharePoint Online o365 Content- and Script Editor WebParts still missing in classic sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, cewp

I am tenant administrator and still got the following problem:

1. I allowed custom scripts in sharepoint admin center and waited 24h
2. I tried the same with the script: Set-SPOsite https://.sharepoint.com -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0
3. I set up a new teamwebsite
4. I enabled Sharepoint publishing infrastructure on site collection level of that teamsite
5. I enabled Sharepoint publishing feature for the teamsite
6. I created an Enterprise Wiki-Subsite under the teamsite
7. I enabled Sharepoint publishing feature for said subsite
8. Content- and Script-Editor WebParts are still missing on that Enterprise-Wiki Subsite

What else do i have to do to enable Content- and script-editor WebParts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to activate publishing features.

After you have enabled custom script for the whole tenant, you need to enable custom script again at **site level** using the same command:

```
Set-SPOsite -Identity https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<site> -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0
```

This works for both Team sites and Enterprise Wiki sites, but not hub sites.

Comment: Sweet mother of god you are great. Thanks a lot, this did it and somehow it was nowhere written to also enable it on site-collection level